# How to do the derivative when an exponent has an exponent

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

I am trying to solve an equation that is in the form of $y(x) = (c + x^2)^{x^2}$. Note $c =$ constant

My initial thoughts are I need to look into using ln and e to solve this. However what I am really unsure how to deal with the exponent on the right of the equation because it has an exponent as well.

i.e the part highlighted in bold confuses me.

Answer (score 2):

Note $\ln y = (x^2) \ln {(c + x^2)}$. Then $$\frac{dy}{dx} \frac{1}{y} = \frac{d}{dx} ((x^2) \ln {(c + x^2)}) \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = y \frac{d}{dx} ((x^2) \ln {(c + x^2)}) = (c + x^2)^{x^2} \frac{d}{dx} ((x^2) \ln {(c + x^2)})$$

Comment: oooohhh. I had headed down the wrong path. I was trying to incorporate e into it as I thought it was a situation where I'd use somethign like e^ln x as an example

Answer (score 2):

One way to deal with it is to take the exponent out by taking a logarithm:

$$\ln(y) = x^2 \ln \left ( c + x^2 \right ).$$

Now when you differentiate, you get $\frac{y'}{y}$ on the left side, and you have something which is not too hard to differentiate on the right side.

This is called *logarithmic differentiation*. It's a common trick for differentiating complicated products/quotients, and is essentially the only way to differentiate functions like $x^x$ or your function.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the more generalized rule
$$\left(f^g\right)'=gf^{g-1}\cdot f' + f^g\log f\cdot g'$$
where $f$ and $g$ are functions of $x$ and the prime denotes differentiation with respect to $x$ as usual.

This simultaneously generalizes the familiar power rule and exponential rule. Take $g$ or $f$ to be constant to recover the familiar rules.

You can derive this rule via logarithmic differentiation.